# Poetry Error: Not enough arguments (missing: "path")

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry

I had poetry running smoothly till yesterday with 1.1.13 version on Python 3.10.4 installed via pyenv
Today I updated poetry with the command

```
poetry self update
```

Now after setting

```
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
```

When I try to create a new project

```
poetry new --src
```

It keeps giving me this error

```
Not enough arguments (missing: "path").
```

I already have my ~/.zshrc with the poetry setup if I am not mistaken on my Apple M1 machine

**My ~/.zshrc file**

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh


export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
# https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#installing-with-the-official-installer
export PATH="/Users/vr/.local/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

Can anyone kindly tell why this is not working? Version of poetry is 1.1.14 after update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `new` you must specify a path, if you want to create a new project inside the current folder, it must be empty, and you should execute it as follows

```bash
$ mkdir my_new_project
$ cd my_new_project
$ poetry new --src .
```

Notice the `.` in the end, this is the path